# Ball joints and boots are constantly in need of replacement?

Tags: honda, civic, ball-joint

I have a 2001 Honda Civic.  Over the past couple of years I have had to have both front lower ball joints replaced multiple times.  The last time I had these replaced I had used my car less than 4,000 miles.  I don't really drive it anywhere that should cause this kind of wear and tear.  Generally, to and from work on a highway.

I am just wondering if there is something bigger going on here that I am unaware of.  Is the shop raking me over the coals?  Or is it possible that a problem exists further upstream that is causing these constant failures?

Comment: maybe your suspension? hows the ride and have they ever been replaced

Comment: suspension is pretty new, rides pretty good for a little sedan

Comment: Get a second opinion to ensue they are actually bad. If the same shop is telling you they need replaced, either they are using bad parts, improperly installing them, or they are cheating you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be that the shop is using a product that uses a plastic bushing in the balljoint. Does the balljoint have a grease fitting on it? If so it should be regreased every oil change. Installation error could also cause premature failure.

You'd have to cut the balljoint open to see what caused the failure.

If you doubt what the shop is telling you you can always check for yourself or have another shop take a look at it.